# Spring cloud - Zuul - custom Filters

Tags: spring, filter, spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-zuul

The Spring cloud Netflix documentation does not have any information about existing Zuul filters. Are there any other resources which explains existing zuul filters, guides on creating a new filter? Also I need to know what priority should I set in my custom filter and whether I need to to use ResponseWappers like in servlet filters?

Comment: It's pretty easy to find filters with your IDE, just check out the hierarchy of ZuulFilter and these filters give a good example for your custom ones. Order depends on what is your filter doing, also the filter type depends on what is your task. If you are rewriting URL-s for example you have to rewrite it before ribbon routing.

Answer (score 4):

To create a customfilter you can extend the class with ZuulFilter and you will have to add @Bean configuration.

```
public class MyFilter extends ZuulFilter {
    @Override
  public String filterType() {
    return "pre";
  }

  @Override
  public int filterOrder() {
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean shouldFilter() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public Object run() {
    return null;
  }
    }
```

Write this definition on the class annotated with springbootapplication

```
@Bean
  public MyFilter myFilter() {
    return new MyFilter();
  }
```

There are 4 types of filter PRE, ROUTING, POST, ERROR I think name explains the purpose you can define the type of filter in FilterType() method above and can also choose the priority.

You can use RequestContext to get the request and response.

These doc might be helpful to get more details:-

1. https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/
2. https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/wiki/How-it-Works