# Spring cloud - Zuul - aggregate responses

Tags: aggregate, spring-cloud, netflix, netflix-zuul

How could Zuul be used to aggregate results of two endpoints? i.e.
Suppose /api/notes request being made.

1. Zuul is suuposed to invoke /notes/from/source/1 and/notes/from/source/2 endpoints
2. Aggregate results receied fom both the endpoints
3. Send aggregated results to client who initiated the results

Can this be done easily with Zuul? If not, I don't see any other facility that Zuul provides other than providing a filter chain.

Answer (score 2):

It can't be done automatically. You need to write a zuul filter to do this.

Comment: Can you please provide some links/ resources on how to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055736/creating-custom-zuul-filters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34179743/spring-cloud-zuul-custom-filters http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28467756/how-do-you-create-custom-zuul-filters-in-spring-cloud

Comment: spencergibb Isn´t it a bad practice to overwhelm Zuul as an API Gateway with response aggregation?